# What is the best way to a get/post action in Rails ? How is resources internally converted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i was wondering what is the better way of creating a get/post actions set standard procedure, in terms of code and routing.

Whenever i need to get a page, i would just create the action and add a route like :

```
  scope :path => '/town', :controller => :town do
    match '/' => :index, :as => 'town'
  end
```

This would allow me to get the town page. If i understand rails routing correctly, this potentially treats /town as a post page as well, but i don't say any real security issue with that.

When i have a post action handled by my controller, i usually start the functions there by a comment :

# POSTED ACTIONS

because i want to separate get/post actions. And i add a similar route as above. I suppose that for a post action , I would do a match :via post probably. I would be really interested in seeing how Rails internally converts "resources :whatever", in order to do the same for my routes.

Could you please explain how you create your posted actions and if somebody is also aware of what "resources :users" actually converts to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resources :things` translates into the following:

```
Verb    Path             Action (method in ThingsController)
----    ----             ------
GET     /things          index
GET     /things/new      new
POST    /things          create
GET     /things/:id      show
GET     /things/:id/edit edit
PUT     /things/:id      update
DELETE  /things/:id      destroy
```

which could be written manually as

```
get    'things'          => 'things#index', :as => :things
get    'things/new'      => 'things#new',   :as => :new_thing
post   'things'          => 'things#create'
get    'things/:id'      => 'things#show',  :as => :thing
get    'things/:id/edit' => 'things#edit',  :as => :edit_thing
put    'things/:id'      => 'things#update'
delete 'things/:id'      => 'things#destroy'
```

If you want to use `resources` minus certain actions, you can do

```
resources :things, :except => [:edit, :update]
```

The [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is a great resource for learning about the routing system.